# Regd: WebDriver on secure Certificate

Tags: webdriver

I have been using WebDriver for past 6 months.

There are couple of issues am facing right now [Version 2.3.1]:

a) when i try to get the element for the override link on the security certificate [https] page in IE through webdriver findElement, its not able to find that element but the selenium RC works fine.

Then i got a fix for tht by using:
webDriver.navigate().to(javascript:document.getElementById('overridelink').click());

Note : 
I tried using the below code to fetch the element on security certificate page , but it returns 
the body element

WebElement activeElement() [WebElement with focus, or the body element if no element with focus can be detected.], why its not able to pick the element by using findelement ?

b)  i connected the remote network through SSL for running the webdriver test, am not able to click the override link on secure certificate [https] page?

c) is it better approach implementing webdriver [currently am using this] directly instead of using any framework like jbehave ?

Please provide your suggestions
Thanks,
Jayaraj A

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for workaround!

For Java, your solution will look just a bit different and it helped me:

```
//driver is initialised somewhere before, for example, as RemoteWebDriver     
driver.navigate().to("javascript:document.getElementById('overridelink').click()");
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I had similar problems. Webdriver doesn't seem to have complete information on
the Certificate error page for some reason.
I'm on Windows XP SP3, running IE 7 with Python/Webdriver
I'm using this hack to get around the certificate error page:
(Help, I still can't get freeeking Markdown to format a code block...)

---

```
#!/c/Python27/python

import win32con
import win32gui

def certificate_continue():
    """
    Find the IE Window that has a Certificate Error and try to continue anyway.
    We'll use the win32 modules to find the right window & child window,
    then write some Javascript into the address bar and execute to continue.
    """
    def _enumWindowsCallback(hwnd, windows):
        """
        Cannibalized from Gigi Sayfan (WindowMover)
        http://www.devx.com/opensource/Article/37773/1954
        This appends window information as a 3-tuple to the list
        passed into win32gui.EnumWindows()
        """
        class_name = win32gui.GetClassName(hwnd)
        # apparently win32gui.GetWindowText() only works to get the text
        # on a button or a label not really for edit windows.
        text = win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd)
        windows.append((hwnd, class_name, text))


    def _get_certificate_error_window():
        """
        all_windows[] gets filled up with a list of tuples, then loop through
        it filtering on class and the window text (title bar text).
        Assumes only one 'Certificate Error' window.
        """
        all_windows = []
        win32gui.EnumWindows(_enumWindowsCallback, all_windows)
        for win in all_windows:
            class_name = win[1]
            title_bar_text = win[2]
            if class_name == 'IEFrame' and \
                     'Certificate Error: Navigation Blocked' in title_bar_text:
                return win

    def _get_edit_text(hwnd):
        """
        This function courtesy of Omar Raviv with huge help from Simon Brunning.
        http://www.brunningonline.net/simon/blog/archives/000664.html
        """
        buf_size = win32gui.SendMessage(hwnd, win32con.WM_GETTEXTLENGTH, 0, 0)
        buf_size += 1 # don't forget that null character boys...
        buffer = win32gui.PyMakeBuffer(buf_size)
        # odd, we're telling them how big the text is that they're giving
        # back to us
        win32gui.SendMessage(hwnd, win32con.WM_GETTEXT, buf_size, buffer)
        # don't need the null character now for Python
        return buffer[:buf_size]


    def _get_address_bar(parent_handle):
        """
        There appears to be several 'Edit' windows within each browser window.
        From Microsoft: If a child window has created child windows of its own,
        EnumChildWindows enumerates those windows as well.
        """
        childwins = []
        win32gui.EnumChildWindows(parent_handle, _enumWindowsCallback,
                                  childwins)
        for win in childwins:
            child_handle = win[0]
            class_name = win[1]
            if 'Edit' in class_name:
                edit_text = _get_edit_text(child_handle)
                if 'http://' in edit_text or 'https://' in edit_text:
                    return child_handle  # then this must be it...


# begin certificate_continue
    target_win = _get_certificate_error_window()
    try:
        cert_err_handle = target_win[0]
    except TypeError:
        print "OK, no Certificate Error window available"
        return(1)

    address_bar_handle = _get_address_bar(cert_err_handle)
    # any better way to check the handle ?
    if not win32gui.IsWindow( address_bar_handle):
        print "Choked getting IE edit window"
        return(1)

    # now, need to send this JavaScript text to the browser Address Bar
    javascript_continue = 'javascript: var continue_element = document.getElementById("overridelink"); continue_element.click();'
    win32gui.SendMessage(address_bar_handle, win32con.WM_SETTEXT, 0,
                         javascript_continue)

    # OK, and finally, send a carriage return to the address bar
    # This last abomination, courtesy of Claudiu
    # http://stackoverflow.com/#questions/5080777/
    # what-sendmessage-to-use-to-send-keys-directly-to-another-window
    win32gui.SendMessage(address_bar_handle, win32con.WM_KEYDOWN,
                         win32con.VK_RETURN, 0)
    return(0)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    status = certificate_continue()
    exit(status)
```

Comment: how do you use this? I do a webdriver get on the ssl url and the 'Certificate Error: Navigation Blocked' page appears. How do I call this to handle the page?